# Integrating OBIEE with web application

Tags: java, web-services, obiee

I have a requirement where I need to integrate OBIEE reports with my J2EE based web application. On going through the available documentation, I have understood there are various ways of integration. I am particularly looking for below two methods:

1. Go-URL
2. Web service

I wanted to know how will I get to know which web service to use and how. Also, what is the response format of web services, can it be a PDF or image document? I want to integrate using web services because I want control of the report document in my web application and store it in database or a DMS system or digitally sign it before providing it to end user.

How will I know the web service WSDL and pass the filter parameters in the web service request and also specify the response format of the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Web Services documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e16364/soa_overview.htm#BABHJJAC

Update:

From what I can see, the OBIEE web services don't support export to PDF/image.

If you want to work directly with PDFs, you might need to look at using BI Publisher (BIP) instead, which also supports [Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22259/reportservice.htm#T569713). BI Publisher can query existing OBIEE analyses and RPDs. You can also call BIP directly from within a Java application using the [available APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22259/javaapis.htm).

Comment: But is it possible to get a report in some PDF/Image format as a response from OBIEE web service? Does OBIEE provides this feature? If yes, what web service can I use for it?

Comment: I've amended my answer.

Comment: Tried to use presentation service to get the report but not able to understand on how to do it as I don't understand OBIEE much.Do you have a sample code for presentation web service integration?